# Format of URL to Read JSON from Google Docs Document (Not Sheets Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-docs

I know the URL format to read JSON from a Google Sheets spreadsheet, which is as follows:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/[sheet_id]/[sheet_number]/public/basic?alt=json
```

Is there a similar URL format to read JSON data from a Google Docs Document?

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer in case anyone else runs into this issue:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=[document_id]&exportFormat=[format]
```

Where `[format]` could be `txt`, `html`, or `pdf`.

Cheers!

Comment: This works, but keep in mind the Doclist API has been shut down. So it will probably stop working in the future.